# How to display the registered output of a list using with_items?

Tags: ansible

I need to check if certain user accounts exist on a long list of machines. I don't want to use a verbose output while running this so I have the following:

```
  - name: Check if user ids exist on machine
shell: "id {{ item }}"
with_items:
  - user1
  - user2
  - user3
  - user4
  - user5
  - user6
  - user7
  - user8
register: status
failed_when: false

- name: Output of Previous task
  debug:
    var: "status.stderr_lines"
```

This doesn't work and I understand why but I'm not sure how to access the registered outputs.

Comment: Did you try `debug: var=status` and see what it holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply a `with_items` to a task and use a register named `status`, the results of the tasks will end up in `status.results` (a list).

You can see it by simply debugging `status` itself.

Comment: awesome, but now how do i make it so that it only outputs the stderr and stdout for each item?

Comment: You could apply a `with_items` for the `debug` too?